# Proper way to insert a scalar variable into a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create a tensor with entries being different "versions" of the same variable (e.g. different powers) for which ultimately a gradient need to be computed. For example

```
v: Variable
# Now the corresponding tensor should look like:
M = [[ 1    , v    ],
     [ v**2 , v**3 ]]
# Followed by some computation involving `M`,
# then compute gradient w.r.t. `v`.
```

I'm not sure what is the best approach to achieve this. Right now I came up with two options but they feel both somehow "hacky":

- Using multiple calls to [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack),
- or using a combination of multiplication and summation of auxiliary tensors.

Here's the code example:

```
import tensorflow as tf


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 2))
v = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.float32)
# Option 1.
M = tf.stack(
    [tf.stack([1   , v   ]),
     tf.stack([v**2, v**3])]
)
# Option 2.
M = (
             tf.constant([[1, 0], [0, 0]], dtype=tf.float32)
    + v**1 * tf.constant([[0, 1], [0, 0]], dtype=tf.float32)
    + v**2 * tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 0]], dtype=tf.float32)
    + v**3 * tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)
)
z = tf.matmul(x, M)
result = tf.tensordot(z, z, (1, 1))
gradient = tf.gradients(result, v)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    r, g = sess.run([result, gradient], feed_dict={x: [[1, 2]]})
```

Is there another (more dedicated) way to accomplish this task? Are there reasons to prefer one of the above methods over the other?

## Edit

The above example indicates a polynomial dependency of the tensor elements on the variable `v` however I am interested in the more general case where the elements can have *any* (differentiable) functional dependence on the variable `v`; for example:

```
# More general example.
M = [[ v**2         , sin(v) / v        ],
     [ cos(sqrt(v)) , exp(v + constant) ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the operation in one line with `tf.range` and `tf.reshape`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
v = tf.Variable(2)
M = tf.reshape(v ** tf.range(4), (2,2))
# becomes: tf.reshape(v ** [0,1,2,3], (2,2))
# becomes: [[v**0, v**1], [v**2, v**3]]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    g = sess.run(M)

# result is: 
# array([[1, 2],
#       [4, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: That works for the specific example I gave in the OP and as such it is a good answer. However I would like to address the more general case where the tensor elements can have *any* functional dependence on the variable `v`; for example `[[v**2, sin(v)/v], [cos(v), sqrt(v)]]`. I should've emphasized this more in my question. Nevertheless your answer works well when working with polynomial dependencies.